# Ajax call Web Service in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) localhost:45562/WebService1.asmx/btn

WebService not load via ajax call, if I write same code in WebForm.aspx.cs everything work nice

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            sendAjaxRequest();
        });



        function sendAjaxRequest() {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "WebService1.asmx/btn",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{ surname: 'Axakalov', name: 'Sunnatilla' }",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: responseOut,
                error: function (error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        };


        function responseOut(response) {
            $("#out").html(response.d);
        }

    });
```

**WebService1.asmx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication9
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string btn(string surname, string name)
    {
        return surname + " " + name;
    }

}
```

}

Please help, why webservcise1.asmx was not found

Comment: Did you miss slash in the path of service? `/WebService1.asmx/btn`

Comment: I tried , it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have given correct URL then..

You need to enable `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` attribute:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{   
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string btn(string surname, string name)
    {
        return surname + " " + name;
    }  
}
```

Comment: [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public string btn(string surname, string name)
    {
        return surname + " " + name;
    }, ERROR

Comment: Thank you @Neel, I didnt' read this comment :) ==> // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.